# In Swift, how to stop all the process until datas retrieved from parse.com in UICOLLECTIONVIEW

Tags: swift, parse-platform, uicollectionview, grand-central-dispatch

In CollectionView I am displaying datas from parse.com. Successfully retrieved. But unable to display in the cell. I am receiving error as Array outbound. I found out the mistake, parse is running as asynchronous. But, before parse end, collection view gets loaded. So I unable to display values in the cell. It is throwing an error. How to stop all the process until parse get loaded completely? Kindly guide me. 
MY CODING IS BELOW:

```
//VIEWCONTROLLER having collectionView

var myList : NSArray = NSArray()

let obj_par = parse_retrive()
obj_par.parse_DB() //DATAS GOING TO RETRIVE FROM PARSE

story_collection_view.reloadData() //RELOADING COLLECTIONVIEW

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        println("fifth")

        if(collectionView == date_collection_view)
        {
         :
         :
            return cell
        }

        else

        {
            var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("story_read", forIndexPath: indexPath) as story_reading_cell

  cell.story_title.text = myList.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? String //ERROR: ARRAY OUTBOUND OF INDEX

            return cell
        }

    }
```

//PARSE_RETRIVE CLASS

```
func parse_DB() {

        println("SECOND 10")

        par_query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({(NSArray objects, NSError error) in

            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog("error " + error.localizedDescription)
            }
            else {
                println("SECOND 13")
                let sql_store_obj1 = sql_to_store() //THIRD CLASS
                self.parse_obj_arr = NSArray(array: objects)
                var j : Int = self.parse_obj_arr.count
                for (var i : Int = 0; i < j; i++) {
                    self.par_object = self.parse_obj_arr.objectAtIndex(i) as PFObject
                    self.sto = self.par_object["story_title"] as String        //STORY TITLE FROM PARSE
                    self.sto_con = self.par_object["story_content"] as String  //STORY CONTENT FROM PARSE

                    self.sto_tit.append(self.sto)        //STORING IN ARRAY VAR
                    self.sto_cont.append(self.sto_con)   //STORING IN ARRAY VAR

                } //FOR ENDING

                sql_store_obj1.sto_title_arr = self.sto_tit
                sql_store_obj1.sto_content_arr = self.sto_cont
                sql_store_obj1.parse_to_sql()

            }//ELSE ENDING

        }) //PARSE QUERY ENDING

        println("SECOND")

    }
```

//THIRD CLASS

```
func parse_to_sql() {

        let appDel : AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
        let context : NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
        let ent = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Sad", inManagedObjectContext: context)
        var newStory = story_sad_managed(entity: ent!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)

        newStory.story_title = sto_title_arr
        newStory.story_content = sto_content_arr

        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "STORY")
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "story_title = %@", sto_title_arr)
        result  = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!

        let sto_page_obj = story_page()
        sto_page_obj.myList = result //1st CLASS ARRAY 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> ***NOTE:*** All code is in Objective-C, but the translation for this particular code should be trivial. If someone wants to edit my post to include the Swift code, please feel free, but please leave the Objective-C in the post.

What I do (for `UICollectionView` or `UITableView`) is create a property, normally called `isLoading` like this:

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL isLoading;
```

I normally initialize it like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // This could also be done in viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear
    // based on your needs/desires
    self.isLoading = NO;
    [self loadData];
}

- (void)loadData {
    if (self.isLoading == YES) {
        // Just in case a "loadData" call is made while one is pending...
        return;
    }
    // Prevent this method from firing again until 
    // data loading is done; prevent UICollectionView
    // from attempting to display missing data
    self.isLoading = YES;
    
    // Do whatever you need to do...
    
    // Clean up and prepare for UICollectionView
    self.isLoading = NO;
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

Now, the real secret is, of course, that you have to implement logic in your `UICollectionViewDataSource` methods to display data conditionally based upon `self.isLoading`, like this:

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (self.isLoading == YES) {
        // You might want to return 0 or 1, 
        // depending on whether you have a "loading"
        // placeholder cell. Assume you do:
        return 1;        
    } else {
        // Return whatever is the correct number here
    
    }
}
```

Generally, that's all I need to get my screen to delay loading the `UICollectionView` until the Parse query has returned correctly.

When I have multiple queries that will run concurrently, all of which should return before I consider data loading to be complete, then I create a `BOOL` property for each of them, setting the flags as appropriate, and I funnel all query returns through a `checkIfDone` method. Something like this:

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL data1Loaded;
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL data2Loaded;
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL data3Loaded;
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL data4Loaded;

- (void)loadData {
    if (self.isLoading == YES) {
        return;
    }
    self.isLoading   = YES;
    self.data1Loaded = NO;
    self.data2Loaded = NO;
    self.data3Loaded = NO;
    self.data4Loaded = NO;

    // Call each of the separate data loading methods...
    [self loadData1];
    [self loadData2];
    [self loadData3];
    [self loadData4];

    // Notice that I don't do any reloadData calls here...

}

- (void)loadData1 {
    PFQuery *query = // Some query creation...
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:
        ^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (error != nil) { 
                // Handle "got error"

            } else {
                // Handle "got good data"

            }
            // Either way, #1 is done, so:
            self.data1Loaded = YES;
            // This pattern checks for completion and
            // runs the completion code only when all
            // 4 (in this case) items/queries have returned
            [self checkIfDone];
        }
     ];
}

- (void)checkIfDone {
    if (self.data1Loaded == YES && 
        self.data2Loaded == YES && 
        self.data3Loaded == YES && 
        self.data4Loaded == YES) 
    {
        // Clean up and prepare for UICollectionView
        self.isLoading = NO;
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    }
}
```

> ***Caveat:*** This assumes that any subsequent calls to `loadData` will occur in the background and that any subsequent calls to `[collectionView reloadData]` will only take place at the end of your query calls. If anything else might call `reloadData` in the meantime, you will need more advanced logic to ensure that the correct data is loaded correctly.

> ***Side Note:*** When doing something like this, don't forget to show the user an indication that work is progressing. I like to use the open source `MBProgressHUD`. It's available [here on GitHub](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD). I have found it invaluable for doing exactly what you're talking about doing.